# Как сделать так, чтобы таймер акции после окончания выводил сообщение?

Tags: javascript

Есть код на фидле, необходимо добавить всплывающее окно после завершения акции

```js
var deadline = new Date("2018, 7, 19");
initializeClock('clock', deadline);

function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  return {
    'total': t,
    'days': days,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
  var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
  var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
  var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

  function updateClock() {
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

    daysSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.days).slice(-2)
    hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

    if (t.total <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }
  }
  if (daysSpan <= 0 && hoursSpan <= 0 && minutesSpan <= 0 && secondsSpan <= 0) {
    document.alert('sdfsdf');
  } else {
    updateClock();
    var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="stock text-center">
  Акция закончится через
  <span id="clock">
        <span class="days"></span>:<span class="hours"></span>:<span class="minutes"></span>:<span class="seconds"></span>
  </span>

  <script>
  </script>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Zebren/qdn2emzu/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Есть код на фидле, необходимо добавить всплывающее окно после завершения акции

Проверять внутри `updateClock`.

```js
var deadline = new Date("2018, 7, 4 "); // добавьте чтобы проверить hh:mm:ss
initializeClock('clock', deadline);

function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  return {
    'total': t,
    'days': days,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
  var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
  var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
  var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

  function updateClock() {
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);
    //----------------------------------------------------------------
    // Акция всЁ
    if (t.total < 0) { // Ended .....
      daysSpan.innerHTML = '00'
      hoursSpan.innerHTML = '00';
      minutesSpan.innerHTML = '00';
      secondsSpan.innerHTML = '00';
      return;
    }
    daysSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.days).slice(-2)
    hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

    if (t.total == 0) { // <------ Times is up
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
      alert('Times UP~');
    }
  }
  if (daysSpan <= 0 && hoursSpan <= 0 && minutesSpan <= 0 && secondsSpan <= 0) {
    console.log('sdfsdf');
  } else {
    updateClock();
    var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="stock text-center">
  Акция закончится через
  <span id="clock">
<span class="days"></span>:<span class="hours"></span>:<span class="minutes"></span>:<span class="seconds"></span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: А как закончить таймер? В условии просто равно 0 не подходит, там необходимо меньше или равно. Тогда выводится алерт, но таймер продолжает отсчет в минус...

Comment: `new Date("2018, 7, 4 20:00:00");` - поменяйте 20 на свое время. Желательно как можно ближе к минуте +- от того времени которое у нас на компе.

Comment: Все ровно считает в минус

Comment: @Zebren если минус значит не правильно выставили время, который у вас час?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Zebren/qdn2emzu/8/ 
Время 21:51

Comment: @Zebren 21:53:00  или 21:54:00 удачно?

Comment: Удачно, но при обновлении страницы, счетчик считает в минус, а мне надо чтобы он остановился и больше не считал

Comment: @Zebren добавил. Если выличил ставьте галочку.